# How to pass firebase value/key as parameter in functions javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

Is it possible to pass the key of where the data is located as a parameter in function?

For example;

```
function myfirebasedata(myDivTag, value){
  var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
  ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();    
    myDivTag.innerHTML = data.value.age;
  });    
}
```

and then I could call this like:

```
myfirebasedata(divTagAgeJames, James);
myfirebasedata(divTagAgeBob, Bob);
....
....
```

So for example, when the first instance of the function is run/called `myfirebasedata(divTagAgeJames, James);`

it should replace the keywords in the reference of firebase code above to;

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();    
  myDivTagJames.innerHTML = data.James.age;
});
```

Update:

[image]

Comment: Based on your response to nicfo, can you share the firebase record structure that you're pulling in from /dinosaurs?

Comment: Hi, @Lance thats just a sample URL I used. Please see my update with the data structure I have.

Answer (score 1):

You could try one of those:

1.[snapshot.child()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/child.html)

```
ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var age = snapshot.child(value).val().age;    
    myDivTag.innerHTML = age;
});
```

2.[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```
ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();    
    myDivTagJames.innerHTML = data[value].age;
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you are passing a variable containing a string of an existing child of your firebase?

Comment: Yep, I have a variable called value, inside which I have another variable called age that contains the string I want to retrieve.

Comment: oh, then i'm sorry, i misunderstood your question.